# Windows XP, pipe StdOut to Commandline

Tags: windows-xp, command-line-interface, redirect, redirection, stdout

As an example, I would like the following commands to put a dir listing with all subdirectories to StdOut

```
copy con test
/s^Z
dir `test`
```

So, after lines one and two, there's a file in the current directory called `test` containing `/s`.  Line three doesn't work, of course, but I would like the result to be the same as

```
dir /s
```

.  Perhaps a better for line 3   is

```
echo `test`
```

where I hope the result is

```
/s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backticks do not work the same in `cmd` as `bash`.  You may be able to play around with `type` which is *roughly* equivalent to `cat`.  Redirection isn't a high point for `cmd`, but the following may work[ish] for what I think you're asking:

```
COPY CON TEST
/S^Z
FOR /F %A IN ('TYPE TEST') DO ( DIR %A )
```

Replace `%` with `%%` if this will be run from a batch file instead of the command line.

Comment: Yikes, that's a terrible answer.  Unfortunately, it looks like you're right. :(

Comment: @Limited Sorry for the terrible answer. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this? Are you building a `cmd` script to accept user input or something?  If you wish to expand your question, I may be able to provide a better answer.